# Marklogic XML read throwing jersey multipart exception

Tags: json, xml, jersey, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am reading XML stored in Marklogic with below code

```
            // get a manager for text documents
            XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();

            // create a handle to receive the document content
            DOMHandle handle = new DOMHandle();

            // create a handle to receive the document metadata
            DocumentMetadataHandle metadata = new DocumentMetadataHandle();

            // read the document content
            docMgr.read(documentPath, metadata, handle); //documentPath is the document's URI
```

But above read method is throwing exception as below

```
Dec 17, 2015 8:38:04 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/mixed; boundary=Boundary_1_1651318690_1450364883614 was not found
Dec 17, 2015 8:38:04 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
```

My maven coonfig is as below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is this due to conflict with these 2 jars, or any other issue ?

Comment: Try and add [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart/1.17.1)

Comment: Tried jersey-multipart, did not worked out.